# how can i locate element and get the number by use selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

[image]

I am trying to use selenium to locate this element and get the number this element, but I need selenium to get the number 8864.00 How can I locate this element and get thenumber

HTML:

```
<div class="hidden-xs" style="position:fixed;z-index:2456;top:1em;right:0em;background-color:#fff;">
                <table class="table cart table-hover table_price" id="current_price">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2">Bid</th>
                            <th colspan="2">Ask</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th><div style="width:35px;">Size</div></th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th><div style="width:35px;">Size</div></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td class="price_bid">334</td><td class="price_bid">8,858.00</td><td class="price_ask">8,870.00</td><td class="price_ask">210</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="price_bid">286</td><td class="price_bid">8,858.50</td><td class="price_ask">8,869.50</td><td class="price_ask">8,832</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="price_bid">287</td><td class="price_bid">8,859.00</td><td class="price_ask">8,868.50</td><td class="price_ask">490</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="price_bid">315</td><td class="price_bid">8,860.00</td><td class="price_ask">8,868.00</td><td class="price_ask">367</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="price_bid">1</td><td class="price_bid">8,860.50</td><td class="price_ask">8,867.50</td><td class="price_ask">7,044</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="price_bid">5</td><td class="price_bid">8,862.00</td><td class="price_ask">8,867.00</td><td class="price_ask">400</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="price_bid">10</td><td class="price_bid">8,862.50</td><td class="price_ask">8,866.50</td><td class="price_ask">3,253</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="price_bid">286</td><td class="price_bid">8,863.00</td><td class="price_ask">8,866.00</td><td class="price_ask">56</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="price_bid">286</td><td class="price_bid">8,863.50</td><td class="price_ask">8,865.50</td><td class="price_ask">400</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="price_bid">634</td><td class="price_bid">8,864.00</td><td class="price_ask">8,864.50</td><td class="price_ask">921</td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

could you help me again i need last of td element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, *you are looking to get the "bid price" from the last row in the table*.

There are a few possible solutions here:

- XPath and its [`last()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/last):

  ```
  last_row = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id = 'current_price']/tbody/tr[last()]")
  size, price_bid = last_row.find_elements_by_class_name("price_bid")
  print(price_bid.text)
  ```

  Note that as there are 2 elements with class `price_bid` in each row, we are getting both and unpack into `size` and `price_bid` variables here
- getting all elements matching a specific selector and getting the last one with Python:

  ```
  last_price_bid = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table#current_price tr td.price_bid")[-1].text
  print(last_price_bid.text)
  ```

  This is though, generally speaking, a waste of resources and have poor performance as we are instantiating lots of `WebElement` instances but using a single one.
- basically, any combination of the above. For example, you can get directly to the last bid price with:

  ```
  last_price_bid = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id = 'current_price']/tbody/tr[last()]/td[2]")
  print(last_price_bid.text)
  ```
- convert the whole table into a Python list of bid and ask prices:

  ```
  prices = []
  for row in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table#current_price tbody tr"):
       size_bid, price_bid, price_ask, size_ask = row.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")

       prices.append({
           "size_bid": size_bid.text, 
           "price_bid": price_bid.text,
           "size_ask": size_ask.text,
           "price_ask": price_ask.text
       })

  print(prices[-1]["price_bid"])
  ```

  This option gives more flexibility to query the prices table in case you need to process values from other rows as well.
- you could even get the raw HTML of the table (with e.g. `.get_attribute("outerHTML")`) and put it into a pandas DataFrame via [`read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html)

As you can see, there is a number of different ways to parse out this table. Hope the options above give you enough material to figure out the best approach.